# Удаление драйвера nvidia debian

Tags: linux, debian, nvidia

Debian 10. Был установленный драйвер с сайта нвидиа 390.132. Теперь хочу удалить его и поставить пакет xserver-sorg-video-nvidia-340xx. Но при установке вылазит окно (nvidia-installer-leanup) с сообщением мол типо у вас установлен драйвер нвидиа, но для продолжение нужно его удалить. После появляется предложение ввести ответ [default (N)o]:

И при попытке ввести что n что N что no No что y Y yes Yes ничего не происходит. Как удалить эту дрянь?) Также при попытке вывести dpkg -l | report nvidia список пуст

Answer (score 0):

Был установлен с сайта драйвер версии 390.132 (вроде), после установки драйвера я удалил инсталятор. Немного попользовавшись, решил попробовать 340 драйвер, и перед его установкой надо было удалить преждний, выполнив запуск установочного файла с ключом `

> --uninstall

На этот момент у меня был только 340 йстновчный файл. Через него не получалось выпонить удаление, пришлось качать снова файл с сайта и через него запускать удаление.